# Getting error :app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed

Tags: android

[image: Error![flavor]I tried to generate a signed APK yesterday but didnt because I didnt find a "key store path" . When I edit my project and try to run it on the emulator, I get the following error:

app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog.

Im attaching screenshot of the error and the flavor tab too. enter image description here

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a signed APK with Build > Generate signed APK... and follow the steps. You can define a key store path during the steps

Comment: I did but when I try to create new key store , i cant find the key store path. any help?

Comment: During the steps, you can use the 'Create new...' button. A new dialog appears in which you have to supply a path (using the '...' button in the topright corner). Then you can supply a path and give a name to the file.