# android studio error: app-release-unsgined.apk is not signed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error while i try to run my project from Android Studio to Genemotion. It was working perfectly fine and then I signed the app to test it on other phones and ever since I am unable to run it from android studio. No idea what to do, I tried messing around with Gradle Tasks but they didn't workout. 
[image: Error]

I have already seen other posts like these [Getting error :app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230370/getting-error-app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed) but they didn't help

Comment: Which build type are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you don't want to add the to your Gradle file the signing information, you can just change to the debug mode for your current build type:

[image]

If you want to add the signing information to your build.gradle just do the following:

```
signingConfigs {
      release {
          storeFile file("release.keystore")
          storePassword "******"
          keyAlias "******"
          keyPassword "******"
     }
 }
```